# What are the differences between key in dict & key in dict.keys()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I got a problem with python 2.7 recently:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.v == other.v

a1 = A(1)
a2 = A(1)
```

So:

```
print a1 == a2  # True
```

And:

```
d = {a1: 1}
print a2 in d.keys()  # True
```

But:

```
print a2 in d  # False
```

The question is what's the main difference between `a2 ind.keys()` and `a2 in d`? How can I get `a2 in d is True`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2.7, `dict.keys` returns a list of keys and `a2 in d.keys()` will be iterating all the keys linearly to find if `a2` is in the list.

But `a2 in d` will be just doing a O(1) lookup, based on the hash value of the object `a2`, in the dictionary to see if the key `a2` is in `d`.

---

But in your case, problem is entirely different. Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__),

> If a class does not define a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; **if it defines `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable in hashed collections.** If a class defines mutable objects and implements a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Since you haven't explicitly defined `__hash__` function, you are breaking the contract between them and `__hash__` uses the default hashing based on the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) of the object, which will be different for both `a1` and `a2`. So even though `a1` and `a2` are similar, hashing objects will treat them as two different objects, as their hash values are different.

To fix this, you need to define `__hash__` function, like this

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.v == other.v

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.v)

a1 = A(1)
a2 = A(1)

d = {a1: 1}
print a2 in d.keys()  # True
print a2 in d         # True
```